# How can the Android OS identify AndroidX fragments if they are obfuscated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, obfuscation, androidx, android-obfuscation

I am doing a reverse-engineering work related to Android fragments. I found out in many apks (decompiled with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), [dexToJar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar), ...), the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` class is obfuscated. In most of the cases the class members are obfuscated, while in some minor cases, the class name is even obfuscated. I am wondering in these cases, how can the Android OS identify AndroidX fragments in an app at runtime?

Comment: I don't think Android requires to know which class a Fragment [implementation] is. It just loads the class the the Fragment manager (which is also included in the app and thus knows which classes to use) does the rest.

Comment: @Robert  I see your points, but what if the `FragmentManager` class is also obfuscated (which is also very common)?

Comment: As long as it is inside the app all class references are still the same even if they have obfuscated names. So the FragmentManager knows which class is now the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` class no matter what name it has and in which package it is located.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your answer. I see your points but I am now again wondering how Android accesses the obfuscated `FragmentManager`...Anyway, I guess there are some mechanisms. Your answer already solves the question, thanks.